# .php files not being parsed by HTTPD

Tags: php, centos, mime-types

**Update:**

My problem was with httpd.conf after all, not `php.ini`. I was missing the following:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$> SetHandler application/x-httpd-php </FilesMatch>
```

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHPDownload

*(check other answers below too)*

**Original Question**
I'd like a way to test my php.ini file, because my server currently cannot parse *.php* files. I'm having problems with my MimeTypes for PHP and I don't see any errors when I restart HTTPD.

Comment: Are you sure it's not an issue with Apache?

Comment: It was an issue with my httpd config. My non-parsing of php files was actually the most common problem asked in #httpd - http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHPDownload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If apache (or what web server you use) does not pass the control to the php - then you forgot to add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` into your httpd.conf

Comment: you are NOT supposed to enable mod_php using AddType - its pretty much plain wrong (as I was explained to in irc://irc.freenode.net/httpd). Once should use mod_php you and <FilesMatch \.php$> - See http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHPDownload and http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

Comment: @electblake: before being rude - learn how to ask questions and describe all the issue in details. We **could not know** that you have **dynamically** compiled php, not **statically**. You know the difference?

Comment: @electblake: "you are NOT supposed to enable mod_php " --- sure, we are not. But we supposed you are **experienced enough** to know, that you have to load module or compile it statically, because it is **obvious**. So, dude, please be polite and don't teach us, if you cannot ask questions properly!!!

Comment: Sorry. I got reemed out in #httpd and I was told NOT to use AddType (in pretty strong language, which I vented here heh). They told me that using AddType was plain wrong and whomever tells me to use it should be adviced otherwise. BUT - HERE - my question wasn't phrased around that, and I most definitely took it out on you guys. Many apologies.